# Incorrect file initialisation in C

Tags: c, file

I have a piece of coding that is giving me a error. The `File` pointer is throwing a `NULL` error although it is declared correctly.

```
    int PySchFee(Acc *py_User)
{
    FILE *py_Fp;
    int acn_Num,sch_Id;
    float amnt=0;

     system("cls");
    /* printf("Please enter Account Number\n");
     scanf("%d",&acn_Num);
     printf("Please enter School Id Number\n");
     scanf("%d",&sch_Id);*/
     printf("Please enter Amount to pay\n");
     scanf("%f",&amnt);

     if ((py_User->bal-amnt)>=1000)
     {
         py_User->bal= py_User->bal-amnt;
         AppCharge(py_User);
         Rcrd_Write(py_Fp,py_User,NULL);
         Svetyp(py_User,amnt,py_Sch_Fee);
         fclose(py_Fp);
         return 1;

     }
     else
     {
         fclose(py_Fp);
         Error(broke);
         return 0;
     }
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to be calling fopen anywhere ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never assign anything to `py_Fp`, therefore it contains garbage and hence the crash.

You must write something like

```
 py_Fp = fopen("myfile", "w") ;
```

before calling `Rcrd_Write`

Answer (score 0):

You are using `py_Fp` before you initialize it, you should add a statement like `py_Fp = fopen(...);` before you actually use it, such as `Rcrd_Write(py_Fp,py_User,NULL);`.